# Feed image directory to TensorFlow Object Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

How can I efficiently feed an entire directory of JPEG images to TensorFlow's Object Detection API for inference?

I currently have a modified version of the official tutorial Jupyter Notebook [found here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb), combined with a `for` loop to iterate through images in the directory.

To iterate through the images:

```
 for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
          image = Image.open(image_path)
          image_np = load_image_into_np_array(image)
```

Then, within the same for loop, I feed TensorFlow using feed_dict:

```
 output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                                 feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
```

While this works, it causes out of memory (OOM) errors after several images. I am writing detection masks to PNG files, which may contribute to the bloat.

Is there  a more efficient way to feed the images to the model?

While I've read about tf.data and queuing techniques, most descriptions focus on training a model.